# leaflet legend change according to zoom

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I am changing the level of detail of a map in different levels, and I would like to assign different legends in different zoom levels.  Is that possible within leaflet?

Answer (score 0):

yeah you can write an onEachFeature for your layer and than check the zoom level and accordingly do the operation.

Comment: Could you please exemplify? I'm quite new to suit.

Comment: can you post your code snippet so that i can modify

Comment: function onZoomend() {
    var currentZoom = map.getZoom();
    // here you get your current zoom 
 //now you can add your conditions based on thezoom level
 };

map.on('zoomend', onZoomend);

Comment: var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});

legend.onAdd = function (map) {

    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
        grades = ["imagea", "imageb"],
        labels = ["imagea.png","imageb.png"];
  div.innerHTML += '<b>Legend Title</b><br>'  // don't forget the break tag

    for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
        div.innerHTML +=
           (" <img src="+ labels[i] +" height='50' width='50'>") + grades[i] +'<br>';
    }

    return div;
};

legend.addTo(map);

Comment: The code you mentioned, I am already using it but for layers not for legend.

Comment: yeah on the same function create the legends based on the zoom level do something like this inside that function if(currentZoom =="something"){do something}else{do something else}you have to create or show the legend based on the zoom.

Answer (score 0):

I realize now that it was a very simple issue. I just need to write 'remove control':

```
map.on('zoomend', onZoomend);
function onZoomend(){
if(map.getZoom()>13){  
map.removeControl(legend0);}    
    };
```